# В проекте laravel нет папки lang, как её добавить?

Tags: laravel

Был создан проект laravel (через командную строку), но в папке resources нет папки lang, можно ли её как-то добавить? Мне она нужна для корректировки сообщений об ошибке на русском, пока ошибки выводятся на английском.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В последних версиях Laravel папка lang находится в корне проекта, проверьте там.
Можете использовать Laravel Lang - https://laravel-lang.com, с ее помощью добавите те локали, которые необходимы.

```
composer require laravel-lang/common --dev
php artisan lang:add ru
php artisan lang:update
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло)